# Python adding text to a line

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = open('testlines.csv', 'r')
b = a.readlines()
a.close()

for c in range(0,1):
    d = '<' + b[c] + '>'
    d = b[c].replace(',', '><')
    e = re.findall(r'<(.*?)>', d, re.DOTALL)
    print(d)
    print(e[0],e[1],e[2],e[3],e[4],e[5],e[6],e[7],e[8])
```

d does not print right, the < or > at the beginning of the line and the end of the line doesn't show up.  If I reverse the two line to create/modify d then it doesn't replace the commas.  What am I doing wrong here.  I want the replace and I need to add in the < > at the beginning and end so I do the findall and create a multidimensional array in the end once it has split everything apart.

Comment: Well you do `d = b[c]...` after you attached `<>` to it. So the **previous command** is lost.

Comment: A horrible blonde moment.  DUMB on my part.  Sometimes you totally overlook the obvious.  This was real bad on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after you assign `d = '<'+b[c]+'>'`, you **do nothing with `d`**, but **reassign a value to it**. As a result the step where you add `<...>` is lost.

You can solve it by working on `d` instead of `b[c]`, like:

```
for c in range(0,1):
    d = '<' + b[c] + '>'
    d = d.replace(',', '><') # use d instead of b[c]
    e = re.findall(r'<(.*?)>', d, re.DOTALL)
    print(d)
    print(e[0],e[1],e[2],e[3],e[4],e[5],e[6],e[7],e[8])
```